# Javascript Event Doesn't Trigger In Webkit

Tags: javascript

I've got an event listener that fires normally in FireFox, but somehow doesn't in Webkit based browsers.

```
function ProfilePictureFeedback(fileInput, target) {
    fileInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
        var profilePictureData = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsBinaryString(profilePictureData);

        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var result = btoa(reader.result);
            target.style.background = 'url(data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result + ')';
            target.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
        });
    });
}
```

I've looked around for possible duplicate answers, one stating something about `e.preventDefault();`, but I have no idea how that exactly ties in to my problem.

Edit: Forgot to mention that no error messages are shown in the console.

Comment: Try `onchange` instead of `oninput`.  Or is it `onload`, which is not firing?

Comment: Your code shows two event listeners. Which one doesn't fire?

Comment: @llama the 'input' event listener.

Comment: @Teemu onchange worked (thanks), but I do not get why input didn't work?

Comment: Is `fileinput` a `<input type="file">` element? The `input` event triggers when you're typing into an input field, but you don't type into a file selector dialog.

Comment: @Barmar Yes it's an file type input, it somehow worked on FireFox though. Very strange.

Comment: There are some inconsistencies through browsers, this is just one of them.

Comment: @Barmar: The `input` event type doesn't necessarily require typing. For example, you can perform a copy/paste via menus, and it should still fire. Seems odd that Webkit doesn't trigger it. I wonder what the spec mandates.

Comment: Yeah, MDN says it should fire whenever the value is changed. The difference between `input` and `change` is that the latter fires when the change is "committed", which is when you leave the field after changing it.

Comment: This sounds like a WebKit bug to me.

Comment: @Barmar: Yep, here's a bug report: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149398